# Fingerprint driver for Asus s510uq in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: asus, fingerprint-reader

I bought `Asus Vivobook S15` which has a build in `finger print reader` in touch pad. I have installed `Finger Print Gui` but it doesn't detect finger print device. I have also checked `fprint-demo` which also didn't find the  device.

How can I find the `fingerprint device ID` and corresponding driver? No driver listed in `additional driver application`.

Comment: Hi, having the same issue here. Any success?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: Same issue. Why has it been so long without support for this?

Comment: Any update? I wanted to install Linux on my machine

Answer (score 0):

These sensors should be working in the new 1.92 release of libfprint. Not many distributions have incorporated it yet, but you can build it from [source](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint), something along the lines of `meson build && ninja -C build install` from inside that repo.